# Open all files in a directory and subdirectories using bash terminal command?

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh

I have an alias where I can do `open file1.type file2.type` or `open *.type`

What I want is to be able to use this on all subdirectories of my current location. So if I'm in the parent directory and there are two child directories, running the command will be the same as running `open file1.type file2.type child1/file1.type child2/file1.type`

So something like `open -? *.type` is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If running zsh or bash 4.x with the `globstar` option set, `**` will match all directories recursively.

```
#!/bin/zsh
open **/*.type
```

...

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
open **/*.type
```

Answer (score 4):

`find` works for this sort of functionality.  Something like this:

```
find . -type f -name \*.type -exec open {} \;
```

Or in this case, since `open` is an alias, you have to run the shell as the command:

```
find . -type f -name \*.type -exec bash -c open {} \;
```

Comment: Just a note: `find -exec` will mostly not work, if `open` is really an `alias` as OP has mentioned...